# It's possible to use date functions like "strftime"?

Tags: sqlite.swift

I tried to create a expression like this

`let performedDate = Expression<String>("strftime('%Y-%m-%d', performedDate)")`

and then compare with another string using filter method.
But the generated SQL is

`"strftime('%Y-%m-%d', performedDate)" = '2017-08-17'`.

There is a way to remove quotation marks from `"strftime('%Y-%m-%d', performedDate)"` or I have to use raw SQL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a extension on `Expression` type like this

```
 
extension Expression {

    public func strftime(format: String) -> Expression {
        return Expression("strftime('\(format)', \(template))", bindings)
    }
}
```

and then use

`let date = Expression<String>("startDate")`

`let dateFormat = date.strftime(format: "%Y-%m-%d")`

You can use `dateFormat` as projection or in filter method as well.

Comment: I try to use same function but on column with datatype <Date>. So, it is crashing when try to read from output.
/***
let createdFormate = createAt.strftime(format: "%Y-%m-%d")

 for item in try db.prepare(headAngleMaster.select(createdFormate, angle.average)) {
                    if let average = item[angle.average]  {
                        print("\(average)")
                    }
                    let formattedDate = item[createdFormate] //CRASHING HERE
                        print("\(formattedDate)")
                    
                } ***/